# Modified gravitational model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravity, cosmology, dimensional-analysis

In an [f(R) gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F(R)_gravity) model

$$
f(R)=R+\lambda{R_{0}}\left(\left(1+\frac{R^{2}}{R_{0}^{2}}\right)^{-n}-1\right).
$$

What are the units of $\lambda$ and $R_{0}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By inspecting the equation, you should be able to deduce that

$R_0$ has the same dimensions as $R$ (since you are adding $1$ to $\frac{R^2}{R_0^2}$)

$\lambda$ has no dimensions (since you are adding $R$ to $\lambda R_0$ times some dimensionless term)

Comment: And for completeness, [the units of the Ricci scalar are $m^{-2}$](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34977/what-are-the-units-of-the-quantities-in-the-einstein-field-equation)