# Would quantum gravity be renormalized if the number of spacetime dimensions decreased at small distances?

Tags: renormalization, quantum-gravity, spacetime-dimensions

In the discussion below (bottom of page on link) if the number of dimensions of spacetime d was lower than 3 at small distances would a theory of quantum gravity be renormalizable? Is is possible that spacetime has fewer than 3 dimensions at the microscopic level?

[quantum gravity renormalizarion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/724725/)

Answer (score 1):

The idea that spacetime dimensionality becomes lower at small distances/high energies is somewhat vague, but  there are *hints* that this is indeed what happens in several different approaches to quantum gravity.

A non-technical review of this idea could be found in the paper:

- Carlip, S. (2017). *Dimension and dimensional reduction in quantum gravity*. Classical and Quantum Gravity, 34(19), 193001, [doi:10.1088/1361-6382/aa8535](https://doi.org/10.1088/1361-6382/aa8535), [arXiv:1705.05417](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.05417).

**Abstract**

> A number of very different approaches to quantum gravity contain a common thread, a hint that spacetime at very short distances becomes effectively two dimensional. I review this evidence, starting with a discussion of the physical meaning of ‘dimension’ and concluding with some speculative ideas of what dimensional reduction might mean for physics.

From the paper:

> We have seen that many approaches to quantum gravity show indications of dimensional reduction
> near the Planck scale. Taken individually, none of these hints is terribly convincing. Perhaps the
> best evidence comes from asymptotic safety, in which the argument for two-dimensional behavior
> at the ultraviolet fixed point is compelling, and causal dynamical triangulations, in which the
> evidence for flow of the spectral dimension is extremely strong. But for this evidence to be truly
> persuasive, we would have to actually know that quantum gravity has an interacting ultraviolet
> fixed point, as required by asymptotic safety, or that causal dynamical triangulations has the right
> continuum limit; that is, we would have to know how to quantize gravity.
>
> Taken as a body, though, these hints become quite a bit more compelling. It seems rather
> unlikely that so many different approaches to quantum gravity would converge on the same result
> merely by accident. If this convergence is more than coincidence, though, it ought to be possible
> to to find a common thread, a single origin for dimensional reduction that is shared by all of the
> various approaches.