# Units of the metric tensor or how to get the unit right for the line element

Tags: metric-tensor, conventions, dimensional-analysis, si-units, absolute-units

In [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/34978/73067) it is stated that the metric tensor elements have no physical unit, i.e. $[g_{\mu\nu}] = 1$. What is the convention to get the physical unit of the line element $ds = g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ right. I assume that $[dx^0] = s$ (seconds), and $[dx^i] = m$ (meter) for $i=1,2,3$. The flat spacetime,
$$ ds^2 = -c^2dt^2 + dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$$

would suggest that $[g_{00}] = [c^2] = (m/s)^2$.

What is a (the) convention to get the units right.

Comment: There is no universal convention on this. As an example of how conventions can vary, see Dicke, Phys Rev 125 (1962) 2163. He lets the metric have units of distance. I have a detailed discussion in section 5.11 of my GR book, lightandmatter.com/genrel .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical convention is $x_0=ct$, so $[dx_0]=[dx_i]=~\rm m$.

Although people frequently set $c=1$ to simplify things, and then the whole point is moot.