# Dimensions of Stress-Energy-Momentum Tensor

Tags: general-relativity, dimensional-analysis, units, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

The dimension of the [stress-energy-momentum tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) is similar to that of pressure, according to wikipedia.

The stress-energy-momentum tensor $T_{μν}$ is defined as $μ$ momentum in a spacetime box of volume $ν$. So, its dimension must be similar to that of momentum per unit volume.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stress-energy tensor has units of energy density. Indeed as we usually write it the $\mathrm{T}_{00}$ elements is just the energy density i.e. joules per cubic metre.

You are quite correct that the other three diagonal elements $\mathrm{T}_{11}$, $\mathrm{T}_{22}$ and $\mathrm{T}_{33}$ behave like a pressure. For more on this see [Intuitive understanding of the elements in the stress-energy tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/184042/intuitive-understanding-of-the-elements-in-the-stress-energy-tensor). However pressure and energy density have the same dimensions. Pressure is force/area. Multiply the top and bottom by distance and you have force $\times$ distance/volume, and force $\times$ distance is work i.e. energy.

The other elements are a momentum flux i.e. a momentum density times a velocity. Again if you work through the dimensions you'll find this has the same dimensions as an energy density.

Comment: See also [What are the units of the quantities in the Einstein field equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/34979/226902).